# Embedded CSS not working while it does in external

Tags: html, css, position, footer

So I am trying to make my footer stay at the bottom at all time, but just for one specific page, not the whole website. To do that, I used embedded CSS (within head tag) and it didn't work. I pasted the same code in my main css and it worked.
Please help me fix this. This is the code:

```css
/*this works*/
body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -19vh;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Caviar, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
 float: clear;
 width: auto;
}
footer {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFF3D;
}
footer a{
 color: #000000;
}
footer a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>About.</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

   
  <style>
  <!--very specific small CSS for this document-->
 footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
  </style>
</head>
<!--big header-->
    <header>
      <h1 id="mainHeading">Check</h1>
    </header>
<!--close Big header-->

<!--Small Header-->
    <div id="headerSmall">
      <div id="hOneSmall">Check</div>
    </div>
<!--close small header-->

      <div id="background_one">
        <div class="small_head">About.</div>
  <br><br> <span style="font-size: 1.2em;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in laoreet orci. Vestibulum tortor justo, fringilla quis ante vitae, finibus efficitur neque. Duis semper dui nec ornare accumsan. Vestibulum vel cursus neque, sed viverra magna. Praesent vel velit nec velit rhoncus varius eu in nunc. Suspendisse convallis ante sit amet nulla hendrerit condimentum. Etiam placerat a turpis a dignissim. Praesent pretium dolor sit amet condimentum mattis. Quisque condimentum id neque dapibus hendrerit. Vivamus et metus nulla. Donec interdum velit in tellus gravida lobortis. Morbi lacinia venenatis elementum.<br></span><br>
  
  <span style="font-size: 0.8em; text-decoration: italic;">Got a suggest that we could add to our website? Or found any information that is incorrect? Please feel free to contact us at <a href="check.gmail.com">Check</a></span>
      </div>      <!--bg 1-->
    <footer>
      <div>
        <a href="validation/citation.pdf" target= "_blank">Citations</a>
        <br>Copyright &copy; owned by Student of College
      </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<!--very specific small CSS for this document-->` isn't a valid CSS comment. Also, where's your opening body tag?

Comment: Yeah. I was in a hurry that I forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments in CSS would be written like this

`/* very specific small CSS for this document */`

Not:

`<!--very specific small CSS for this document-->`

Corrected version:

```css
/*this works*/
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -19vh;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Caviar, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  float: clear;
  width: auto;
}
footer {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFF3D;
}
footer a{
  color: #000000;
}
footer a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>About.</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <style>
      /*very specific small CSS for this document*/
      footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <!--big header-->
  <header>
    <h1 id="mainHeading">Check</h1>
  </header>
  <!--close Big header-->

  <!--Small Header-->
  <div id="headerSmall">
    <div id="hOneSmall">Check</div>
  </div>
  <!--close small header-->

  <div id="background_one">
    <div class="small_head">About.</div>
    <br><br> <span style="font-size: 1.2em;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in laoreet orci. Vestibulum tortor justo, fringilla quis ante vitae, finibus efficitur neque. Duis semper dui nec ornare accumsan. Vestibulum vel cursus neque, sed viverra magna. Praesent vel velit nec velit rhoncus varius eu in nunc. Suspendisse convallis ante sit amet nulla hendrerit condimentum. Etiam placerat a turpis a dignissim. Praesent pretium dolor sit amet condimentum mattis. Quisque condimentum id neque dapibus hendrerit. Vivamus et metus nulla. Donec interdum velit in tellus gravida lobortis. Morbi lacinia venenatis elementum.<br></span><br>

    <span style="font-size: 0.8em; text-decoration: italic;">Got a suggest that we could add to our website? Or found any information that is incorrect? Please feel free to contact us at <a href="check.gmail.com">Check</a></span>
  </div>      <!--bg 1-->
  <footer>
    <div>
      <a href="validation/citation.pdf" target= "_blank">Citations</a>
      <br>Copyright &copy; owned by Student College
    </div>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```